# Website "moves" a bit

Tags: php, html, css

My website at http://www.oblivionro.net isn't properly vertically-aligned when you click on a different link in the menu.

For example, if you go from the home page to the ventrilo page, you'll notice that the alignment of the website shifts to the right and down a bit. I know a fair bit about php, but I'm not that great when it comes to css and designing websites.

Anyone know what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link does not work. Are you sure that address is correct and live?

Comment: The web address seems not to be working.

Comment: It should be www.oblivionro.net but the issue has been fixed. Thanks.

Comment: I've already fixed this twice, why do people keep removing the link?

Answer (score 5):

Your link doesn't work for me, but I can guess what the problem is. To fix it, add:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll
}
```

That will force the vertical scrollbar to always be visible, so there will no longer be a "shift" when you move between pages that do/do not have a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: My bad, that should be www.oblivionro.net.

Comment: yep, was thinking it was the scroll bar too, checked that URL, sure is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I didn't even think of that haha. It worked fine.